# Numbering equations in an optimization problem

Tags: math-mode, numbering

I am trying to assign numbers to my equations in an optimization problem, however Latex keeps giving one number for the single problem. I have checked multiple sources for any advice, but I have yet to find one satisfactory.

The model is as follows:

```
\begin{equation} 

\begin{aligned}

& \underset{k=1, t\epsilon T, p\epsilon P}{\text{Max}}
& &\sum_{p\epsilon P}(a_{p,k,t}x_{p,t})+\sum_{t=1}^{T}{(1+r)}^{T-t}y_t  \\

& \text{subject to} 
& & f\sum_{ p\epsilon P}x_{p,t}+y_t=B_t , & \forall t \\

&&& k\geq m_k , & \forall k \\

&&& p_i\geq g_{pi,pj} , & \forall i \vee j && j \neq i \\

&&& \sum_{p\epsilon P}\sum_{t\epsilon T} (a_{p,k,t}x_{p,t})+\sum_{t=1}^{T}{(1+r)}^{T-t}y_t \geq B_F \\

\end{aligned}

\end{equation}
```

I synthesize that the problem is due to me using only one equation format, but I've tried with several, but that only gave me errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean to use the `align` environment instead of the `aligned` environment?  `aligned` creates only one equation number for the whole environment. `align` creates a separate equation number for each new line in the environment.

If you want to omit numbering on specific equations, you can do so with the `\nonumber` command.[image]

Try this code instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\title{Equation Numbering}
\begin{document}
\maketitle


  \begin{align}
    & \underset{k=1, t\epsilon T, p\epsilon P}{\text{Max}}
    & &\sum_{p\epsilon P}(a_{p,k,t}x_{p,t})+\sum_{t=1}^{T}{(1+r)}^{T-t}y_t  \\
%
    & \text{subject to} 
    & & f\sum_{ p\epsilon P}x_{p,t}+y_t=B_t , & \forall t \\
%
    &&& k\geq m_k , & \forall k \nonumber \\
%
    &&& p_i\geq g_{pi,pj} , & \forall i \vee j && j \neq i \nonumber \\
%
    &&& \sum_{p\epsilon P}\sum_{t\epsilon T}
    (a_{p,k,t}x_{p,t})+\sum_{t=1}^{T}{(1+r)}^{T-t}y_t \geq B_F
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `alignat`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Max}{Max}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
   & \underset{\substack{k=1, t ∈ T, \\ p ∈ P}}{\Max}\,
  \mathrlap{∑_{p ∈ P}(a_{p,k,t}x_{p,t})+∑_{t=1}^{T}{(1+r)}^{T-t}y_t} \\
   & \text{subject to}
   & \quad & f∑_{ p ∈ P}x_{p,t}+y_t=B_t , & & \quad ∀ t \\
   & & & k\geq m_k , & & ∀ k \\
   & & & p_i\geq g_{pi,pj} , & & ∀ i ∨ j ,\quad j ≠ i \\
   & & & ∑_{p ∈ P}∑_{t ∈ T} (a_{p,k,t}x_{p,t}) + \mathrlap{∑_{t=1}^{T}{(1+r)}^{T-t}y_t \geq B_F }
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]